# Firebase authorization

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Привет всем. У меня появилась проблема с firebase. 
При авторизации человек вводит обычно email и password.
Мне нужно сделать так- вводишь email, если он сущ. то выходит новое окно для ввода пароля.
Может кто нибудь пожалуйста подсказать как это сделать ?
Или по другому как проверить существует ли email, с которым человек зарегистрировался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть метод  [fetchProvidersForEmail()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#fetchProvidersForEmail(java.lang.String)) , который проверяет наличие email в базе. Более подробно описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078531/how-to-find-out-if-an-email-is-already-registered-with-firebase-simple-login)